# fechas mayor menor que

Tags: mysql

Buneas , alguien sabe en mysql en una consulta poner q te traega una fecha dada en adelante e puesto esto pero me trae tambien del 2018-10-20 y 2018-09-25

```
 SELECT idval_val AS id, val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro, val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre, val_aps AS aps, val_id_ase AS ase, val_ciudad AS ciudad
FROM contacto
WHERE val_ciudad =  'cu'
AND val_fecha_registro >=  '2018-10-29'
AND val_id_ase =  '710'
```

si pongo asi solo me devuelve 3 registros pero son del 2018-11-01 
`val_fecha_registro`  es tipo `date`

Comment: Pon la consulta completa y di si `val_fecha_registro` es una columna de tipo `DATE` o  `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

puede ser por que la fecha se lo pasa como una cadena,
una solución seria realizar la conversión al tipo date

```
WHERE val_ciudad =  'es'
AND CONVERT(val_fecha_registro,DATE) >=  CONVERT('2018-10-29',DATE)
AND val_id =  '710'
```

espero sea esto

Comment: si era eso gracias miago

Comment: @JuanJose considera normalizar los datos si puedes, la columna `val_fecha_registro` debería ser de tipo `DATETIME` o `DATE`. Si no siempre tendrás problemas de este tipo cuando tengas que comparar, calcular o mostrar las fechas. Además se podrían registrar fechas erróneas.